# Grep / Find oracle table name from UNIX Shell / SQL Script

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, find

This is the sample update script in (*.sql) file. I have to extract oracle table name from the shell script / sql script in the displayed output below. Also I am attaching the source code below. I tried to accomplish by awk commands,

**CODE:**

```
awk -F'[=&? ]' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i == "from") print (i+1) }' $FILE
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
UPDATE|EVENT.SEASONAL_EVENT_SKU
SELECT|PLANOGRAM_SKU
SELECT|PLANOGRAM_VERSION
SELECT|SEASONAL_EVENT_SKU
```

**EXAMPLE SCRIPT:**

```
update EVENT.SEASONAL_EVENT_SKU
set SEAS_SKU_IND = 'Y'
where SKU_NBR in ( select distinct sku_nbr
               from
             (
               select a.sku_nbr
               from PLANOGRAM_SKU a,
                    PLANOGRAM_VERSION b
               where a.plano_nbr between 9000 and 9999
               and   a.plano_nbr        = b.plano_nbr
               and   a.plano_version_id = b.plano_version_id
               and   b.seas_plano_ind   = 'Y'
               and   a.sku_nbr not in ( select d.sku_nbr
                                        from PLANOGRAM_SKU d,
                                             PLANOGRAM_VERSION e
                                        where d.plano_nbr between 9000 and 9999
                                        and   d.plano_nbr        = e.plano_nbr
                                        and   d.plano_version_id = e.plano_version_id
                                        and   e.seas_plano_ind <> 'Y')
               union all
               select f.sku_nbr
               from SEASONAL_EVENT_SKU f
               where f.sku_nbr not in ( select g.sku_nbr
                                        from PLANOGRAM_SKU g
                                        where g.plano_nbr between 9000 and 9999 )));

COMMIT;
```

Let me know the better approach to do this for 'n' number of scripts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk to set RS to an RE:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ RS="[[:space:]]+"; OFS="|" }
/^(update|set|from|[[:upper:]._]+)$/ {
    if (/^[[:upper:]._]+$/) {
        if (op != "SET") {
            if (!seen[op,$0]++) {
                print op, $0
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        op = (/^from/ ? "SELECT" : toupper($0))
    }
}
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
UPDATE|EVENT.SEASONAL_EVENT_SKU
SELECT|PLANOGRAM_SKU
SELECT|PLANOGRAM_VERSION
SELECT|SEASONAL_EVENT_SKU
```

With other awks, just leave the RS as default and use a loop on fields.

Comment: how do you enhance for other dml (insert,delete,merge) , ddl (create,drop).

Comment: Depends what they look like in your input file. Without seeing an input file that uses them it's hard to guess what will work but add them to the `|`-separated list `/^(update|set|from|[[:upper:]._]+)$/` to start with and then go from there.